# next.js deployed using now missing styles, styles.css 404 response

Tags: css, devops, next.js

I'm building a simple site for a school project using next, and I managed to deploy the next.js app using now, but no styles are being applied. Everything is fine and works (looks) great on localhost but not online (https://spa-ot24z7ugt.now.sh).

I guess it has something to do with the now.json file, but their documentation makes it look like everything will just work out of the box, and it kind of is true, except for the styling. I looked at the documentation and could not find anything and I was wondering if anyone has any experience using now and next.js.

my now.json file:

````
```{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    { "src": "next.config.js", "use": "@now/next" }
  ]
}```
````

link to the deployed site:
https://spa-ot24z7ugt.now.sh

I'm using Head from 'next/head' to generate link a static CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and the fix for me was to include style.css as static build:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "name": "wp-nextjs",
    "public": true,
    "builds": [
        { "src": "package.json", "use": "@now/next" },
        { "src": "static/css/style.css", "use": "@now/static" }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me "_" dirs were being ignored.

Files with an _ as prefix (like _next, _css, _js) are special for jekyll. You can bypass this by creating a
`.nojekyll`
file in the root of your gh-pages repo and pushing it to GitHub.

Refer : https://github.blog/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/